# Select another control in the same table row using Knockout.js

Tags: knockout.js

I'm having a bit of trouble getting my head around a problem I'm having.

What I'd like to do is, when typing in a textbox, to check if the checkbox in the same row is clicked or not.

Could anybody point me in the right direction please?

Thanks,
John

Comment: please post some code so we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

[**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/eyjk9/)

Using [subscribe](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html) and [valueUpdate](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/value-binding.html) (to fire the event as a key is pressed not on blur)

```
var row = function (check, value) {
    this.selected = ko.observable(check);
    this.word = ko.observable(value);
    this.word.subscribe(function (value) {
        if (this.selected()) {
            alert("checked");   
        }
    }.bind(this));
};
var viewModel = {
    rows: ko.observableArray([new row(false, 'a'), new row(true, 'b'), new row(false, 'c')])
};

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

HTML textbox binding:

```
<input type="text" data-bind="value: word, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'" />
```

Comment: Joe, that looks great... I'll try it and and let you know how I get on. Thanks!